# Mysql Cluster 8 - "Jumpy" Auto Increment Values

Tags: mysql

Im using mysql cluster 8 - using PHP  to insert data I keep running into a problem where the Ids jump and then "recover" I.E

```sql
SELECT `MSU_ID`, `MSU_Date_Created` FROM `Material_Spreadsheet_Upload` ORDER BY `MSU_ID` DESC
```

```
603     2020-04-28 10:55:13
602     2020-04-28 10:55:07
601     2020-04-28 10:55:05
600     2020-04-28 10:55:03
599     2020-04-28 10:55:00
598     2020-04-28 10:54:57
```

```sql
SELECT `MSU_ID`, `MSU_Date_Created` FROM `Material_Spreadsheet_Upload` ORDER BY `MSU_Date_Created` DESC
```

```
100 2020-04-28 12:05:28
99  2020-04-28 11:54:49
98  2020-04-28 11:54:47
97  2020-04-28 11:54:45
96  2020-04-28 11:54:39
```

This is obviously a problem, Im not doing anything in-between inserting the data (I.E messing with `auto_increment` values)

Sinse the upgrade to mysql 8 my tables all have comments `NDB_TABLE=READ_BACKUP=1` they enabled this by default [according to the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-ndb-table-comment-options.html) in Mysql 8 but im wondering if this is whats causing the issue

After the upgrade I noticed but then I had to write an run a bunch of SQL queries to fix the issue initially - but it keeps happening and im not sure how to prevent it

Comment: Are you using NDB?  InnoDB Cluster?  Galera?  (If so, please add the appropriate tag to your Question.)

Answer (score 2):

the ids aren't jumpy, that is only an interpretation.

Tables are per definition unsorted, that why you put an order by in your querys.

the ids only serve to be unique and can sol identify a single row.

In a single maschine this happens, because processors have the capability to sort on a basic level if they have the need, mysql it self sorts things too and calls it optimizing. Then there a on heavy performing sytsem many processes which the operating system handles around.

Finally there are clusters that have to guaranty the uniqueness of every id, which usually works fine too.

And of course the table types play also a role see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-tutorial-excerpt/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html

So ignore the sorting of the ids, use it for identifying the rows.

Comment: Im not sure thats correct - the Id should always increment, not go backwards- On further investigation the cluster is storing 2 different AUTO_INCREMENT values for the table on different cluster members. In  your example they provide a start an increment 100 example - you wouldn't expect it to then insert ID 4

Comment: as i said ignire the ids, there is a deterministic algorithm behind it,to garanty uniqueness, and it works.

Comment: I have 100's of tables I cant just ignore it - thanks but this isn't the answer - This behaviour hasn't happened before (4+ years of running)  and isn't expected

Comment: I was wrong here (sorry) - Ill write up a more complete answer at some point with the links